# IBAction to perform operation on another IBAction

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, calculator

Am very new to objective c and have just started writing my first pieces of code so please be gentle with me in your responses.

I decided to try and do a Darts Calculator for my first attempt at programming given that it is essentially a simple subtracting machine.

In my view controller.h file i have the following:

```
-(IBAction)subtractOne:(id)sender;
```

and in viewController.m

```
-(IBAction)subtractOne:(id)sender

{
    accumulator -= 1;
    calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", accumulator];    
}
```

I have set these up for all twenty two scoring buttons and have managed to get that all working fine.

However my difficulty now comes with the double and treble buttons. I need an -(IBAction) which multiplies the nextButtonPressed by two or by three but am unsure of how to proceed with this.

I am not asking for you to write the code for me, but if you could point me in the direction of how I would do this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction) tripleMultiplier:(id)sender;

-(IBAction) tripleMultiplier:(id)sender {
    // Activate the triple multipler if it is inactive, otherwise deactivate it.
    tripleMultiplier = !tripleMultiplier;
}
```

And in other `IBACtions`

```
-(IBAction) subtractOne:(id)sender {
    // If the tripleMultipler is active: 
    accumulator -= (tripleMultipler ? 1 : 3);
    calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", accumulator];    
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your quick response. I'm presuming the first IBAction goes in the header file, the second in the main file and the third piece of code gets embedded in the code i've already written. Is this correct? I have tried this and keep getting errors saying undeclared identifier tripleMultiplier! Any suggestions please? Thanks again.

Comment: @AlanBurnell in your header you need `BOOL tripleMultiplier`, then in your implementation's `init`, `tripleMultiplier = NO` to initialise it.